# PHP $_POST string to JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, http-post

I'm trying to decode json string using following code

```
$jsonString = "[\"a@gmail.com\",\"b@gmail.com\",\"c@gmail.com\"]";
$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($jsonString);
```

This code works fine. But When I `$_POST` this string via form & then try to decode on other page, It shows NULL.

I checked for string value after post on other page & it returns as `"[\"a@gmail.com\",\"b@gmail.com\",\"c@gmail.com\"]";`

But when I try decode this `$_POST` string as follow,  It shows NULL.

```
if ($_POST) {
    $string = $_POST['my_string'];

    $arrayOfEmails=json_decode($string);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: The string is not proper JSON. You'll get a parse error on the first backslash. Echo `$string` to see the issues.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried echoing $string & it looks fine. I even tried without backslash but same issue.

Comment: The output of $string must be `["a@gmail.com","b@gmail.com","c@gmail.com"]` ... it is?

Comment: You can [lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to test the string.